# Rails - Limit action per ip adress for post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Hi I new to rails and currently working on application with option to like posts,I try to limit the action of like to 1 per post , but I can't figure out how,the app doesn't include users so anyone can like post so I think the best way to do that is with IP or sessions , can anyone please give me guide line?

**My Like Action**

```
  def like
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @post.likes += 1
   @post.save
   redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the `post.likes` attribute an array of IPs instead of an integer, then check the array for existence of the requester's IP to determine whether or not they've already "liked" the post.

For a more scalable solution, you'll need a mechanism for tying the "like" action to a particular `User`. You probably want a `Like` model that `belongs_to` a `User` and `Post` to accomplish this.

Comment: So there is no way that i will be able to handle it without users?because the main goal of the app is to work without users...edit:the array idea may be exactly what i need, thanks!

Comment: See the updated answer for an idea of how to accomplish this without a `User` model.

Comment: Hi Chris if i want to store the "likes" in the database as an array instead of int so i have to use PostrgreSQL?

Comment: If you want it to be treated as a PostgreSQL array, yes. However you can use any DBMS you want by storing it as a `text` field in the database and using `serialize :likes, Array`

Comment: i used the serialize method and that works! thank you!